# Possible to export/import remote DB to WAMP server?

Tags: ssh, mysql, putty, wamp, mysqldump

If I needed to gzip a remote database and import it into my WAMP MySQL database I believe the command I should use is -

```
ssh user@server "mysqldump ericdev | gzip" | gunzip | mysql ericcart
```

But how would I run this locally when Putty requires me to connect to a server first and I can't SSH into WAMP.

Comment: Do you have phpMyAdmin access?

Comment: I do, the DB I am trying to gzip over is a GB though so I'd like to not have to export, download, import if at all possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you give this a try yet? It should work. Pay attention to the quotation marks. I'll add some parenthesis for clarity:

`(ssh user@server "mysqldump ericdev | gzip") | gunzip | mysql ericcart`

So, the first command, `ssh user@server "mysqldump ericdev | gzip"`, returns a gzipped DB. That gzipped DB is then piped into  `gunzip` and `mysql` commands. The ssh command is only for the remote server.

Edit: I completely missed the point of the question, let me try again. (Thanks, @RiggsFolly)

You are going to want to install [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html). Cygwin lets you run lots of repackaged linux utilities on Windows, SSH included. Go through the Cygwin setup and choose SSH under the "Net" section (search for it if you need to). After you've installed it, you should be able to open up the Cygwin console and run the `ssh` command.

So that you don't have to use the Cygwin console, I highly recommend [adding the Cygwin Bin directory to the system path](https://superuser.com/questions/27668/how-can-i-add-cygwin-bin-to-the-search-path-in-windows-xp). You may need to reboot after doing that, but you should be able to run your original command right in command prompt or Powershell.

Comment: If he cannot SSH into the server running WAMP ( because it is a windows machine and they dont have an ssh server by default ) How is that going to help??

Comment: @RiggsFolly *Facepalm* I completely missed the point of this. Updating now...

Comment: LOL Better, but that puts a SSH client on the WorkStation, it does not put an SSH server on the WAMPServer machine. I am assuming (s)he does not have access to the server machine or this would not be an issue.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was thinking that there is a remote server with the MySQL Database and Eric has WAMP running locally. Eric, do you have WAMP locally? What is the server running? (I can't directly comment on his post yet...)

Comment: Thanks for all the assistance you guys trying this now. WAMP is installed locally.

Comment: Also great advice in regards to using CYGWIN, I am getting an errno 32 when trying to SSH, unsure why but trying to work that out. Thanks a millio!